# Is there any way to view the Latency in "View Result Table" Listener of Jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

Is there any way to view the column of Latency(lt) in "View Result Table" Listener of Jmeter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of JMeter 2.7 the answer is no.

I created an enhancement request:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53941

And fixed it.

You can use nightly build until official 2.8 is released:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

Read Building JMeter paragraph.